# Vue error with Rangy library: "..." is not a function (but only inside hooks)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vue-component, laravel-mix

For a Vue component, I use the [Rangy library](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) to highlight single words inside a text. This is working fine if Rangy is called from any method inside the `methods` object:

```
let applier = rangy.createClassApplier('some-class');
applier.toggleRange(range);
```

But sometimes I need to restore a certain state on page load, so I tried using the same method inside the `created` and `mounted` hooks. This doesn't work.

Right now, the first lines of the script in my component look like this:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import rangy from 'rangy';
import 'rangy/lib/rangy-classapplier';

export default {

    mounted: function() {
        // Leave function if there is no data in DB to be restored
        if (_.isEmpty(this.mostRecentAnswers))
            return;

        else {
            // ERROR
            let applier = rangy.createClassApplier('some-class');
            // ...
        }
    }
    // ...
}
```

The error message is `TypeError: rangy__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default.a.createClassApplier is not a function at VueComponent.mounted`

I use Vue with Laravel and Laravel Mix (which is a wrapper for Webpack).

What's wrong with my code? Note I also import Lodash and use it inside the hook without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use `rangy.init()` which initializes Rangy if it has not already been initialized:
https://github.com/timdown/rangy/wiki/Rangy-Object#rangyinit

Comment: Did you get createHighlighter() to work? createClassApplier() is working however.

I loaded rangy as a plugin, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend making a Vue plugin out of this to make it easier:

```
// plugins/vue-rangy.js

import rangy from 'rangy'

const VueRangy = {
  install (Vue, options) {
      if (options.hasOwnProperty('init') && options.init) {
        rangy.init()
      }

      Vue.prototype.$rangy = rangy
  }
}

export default VueRangy
```

Then use it like any other plugin:

```
import VueRangy from 'plugins/vue-rangy'

Vue.use(VueRangy, {
  init: true
})
```

Then just use `this.$rangy` in your components.

Comment: Thanks! In fact I did something similar before (and still do so with other libraries), but due to some reason I can't remember stopped doing this with Rangy. Also, there's an even easier (or at least less complex) solution, see my own answer.